# R: Create new variable equal to specific observations of another variable (certain years)

Tags: r, left-join, dplyr

I have panel data on countries: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZB5po_f9srk-u8OGTA6O5P23XtbZCUGyjrLU6I2glrg/edit?usp=sharing

basically:

```
country  year   x   y    z 
a        1991  ##   ##  ##
b        1991  ##   ##  ##
c        1991  ##   ##  ##
d        1991  ##   ##  ##
a        1992  ##   ##  ##
b        1992  ##   ##  ##
```

I want to create a new variable, based on country **c**'s values for variable **x** repeated for all observations...ideally something like:

```
country  year   x   y    z  new
a        1991  ##   ##  ##  1
b        1991  ##   ##  ##  1
c        1991  1    ##  ##  1
d        1991  ##   ##  ##  1
a        1992  ##   ##  ##  2
b        1992  ##   ##  ##  2
c        1992  2    ##  ##  2
```

I've created variables using mutate, and currently I have something like:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(new = country %in% ifelse("c", x, )
```

But I can't quite find the right syntax. If there are any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it.
I initially tried creating a new data frame and using left_join; however, it created a bunch of new observations. If that's an option, I'd be interested as well.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I was able to troubleshoot a workaround with:

```
Panel <- Panel %>%
  mutate(China_NGDP_bnYuan1 = ifelse(Country == "China", Nominal_gdp, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(China_NGDP_bnYuan = sum(China_NGDP_bnYuan1, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

though, there might be some cleaner ways to achieve the same result.

**2nd UPDATE**
It looks like I am able to get the desired result by also using join

First creating a new df with only country c's values:

```
c_x <- df %>%
  filter(Country == "c")
c_x <- c_x %>% select(Year, x)
```

then using a left_join:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

newdf <- left_join(df, c_x, by = "Year")
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `fill`.  If the `##` are `NA` in 'x' column, then do a group by 'year' and `fill` the column with `.direction` specified as "updown"

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
      mutate(new = x) %>%
      group_by(year) %>%
      fill(new, .direction = "updown")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering; however, this appears to give me the variable x for all countries & years, and doesn't specify that I'm looking only for the values of 'x' where country == 'c' , and then match them to years. I should specify that the ##s represent various numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can `arrange` the data by `year` and `country` and increment the count every time the first value in the data occurs.

```
library(dplyr)

Panel %>%
  arrange(year, country) %>%
  mutate(new = cumsum(country == first(country))) -> Panel
Panel
```